# How to get attribute value from element with several attributes

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have this xml file (part of it):

```
<exchangerates xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" type="Valutakurser" author="Danmarks Nationalbank" refcur="DKK" refamt="1">
<dailyrates id="2020-10-23">
<currency code="AUD" desc="Australske dollar" rate="448,83"/>
<currency code="BGN" desc="Bulgarske lev" rate="380,44"/>
```

I want to get the rate from AUD, Australian dollar.

My xpath query looks like this:

```
$result = $xml->xpath("/exchangerates/dailyrates/currency[@code = 'AUD']");
```

It works and deliver this output:

```
Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [code] => AUD [desc] => Australske 
    dollar [rate] => 448,83 ) ) )
```

And now I am stuck. I want the [rate] value. But how? I have solved this in c# using a navigator.
But now I am using php. I could use javascript if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

From the xpath point of view, you just need to add `/@attributeName` to your xpath.

```
/exchangerates/dailyrates/currency[@code = 'AUD']/@rate
```